Calling private json file on Twilio serverless
I've upload 2 json file under Assets (as private) on Twilio serverless, I know that I need a function to let the code access this file, but it seams not working my code:
exports.handler = async function(context, event, callback) {
    const fileName = event.fileName || ''; // Expect a fileName parameter in the request
    const assets = Runtime.getAssets();
    const fs = require('fs').promises;

    // Define the path for known private assets
    const assetPaths = {
        'abc.json': assets['/abc.private.json'].path,
        'def.json': assets['/def.private.json'].path,
    };

    // Check if the requested file is a known private asset
    if (assetPaths[fileName]) {
        try {
            const fileContent = await fs.readFile(assetPaths[fileName], 'utf8');
            // Return the file content with appropriate content type
            let contentType = 'application/json';
            if (fileName.endsWith('.bin')) {
                contentType = 'application/octet-stream';
            }
            return callback(null, new Twilio.Response({
                statusCode: 200,
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': contentType,
                },
                body: fileContent,
            }));
        } catch (err) {
            console.error('Error reading asset:', err);
            return callback(null, new Twilio.Response({
                statusCode: 500,
                body: 'Internal Server Error',
            }));
        }
    } else {
        // If the requested file is not a known private asset, return a 404
        return callback(null, new Twilio.Response({
            statusCode: 404,
            body: 'Not Found',
        }));
    }
};

In more in my main html code I have this:
const abcURL = "my twilio function url ?fileName=abc.private.json";
const defURL = "my twilio function url ?fileName=def.private.json";

What I'm missing?
The purpose of all is to give access to those private file only to the code, making unreachable from others.
Hope You can help with the code!
With different try, I get or the 403 error or the 404 error, instead the code should load the json files.

You can access private files if it's in the project environment, in the assets folder, or if you want you can create a function to be reusable in other functions.
To import files or function in the Serverless environment you need to use "Runtime Client" which handles with paths of functions and files. To get files you need to use "getAssets()" function, or if you need to import a function you can use "getFunctions()" function.
Remember that the function or file that you want to import needs to be .private.
An example of importing a JSON file:
    const myJson = JSON.parse(
    Runtime.getAssets()['/your-file.json'].open());
    
    exports.handler = async function(context,event,callback) {
    const mappingMyJson = myJson.map(json => ...)
    ...
    return callback(null, "success")
    }

An example of importing a function file:
    const {searchZipCode} = require(Runtime.getFunctions()['/path-to-function'].path)
    
    exports.handler = async function(context,event,callback){
    const zip = await searchZipCode(event.zip)

    return callback(null, zip)
    }

Update
I create a new Serverless project with the follow structure:
project-root/
├── assets/
│   └── test.private.json
└── functions/
    └── getPrivateFile.js

The function basically will get the private file and return its content.
const fs = require('fs').promises

exports.handler = async function (context, event, callback) {
  const { fileName } = event
  const assets = Runtime.getAssets()

  const assetsPath = {
    'test.json': assets['/test.json'].path,
  }

  if (assetsPath[fileName]) {
    try {
      const fileContent = await fs.readFile(assetsPath[fileName], 'utf8')
      let contentType = 'application/json'
      if (fileName.endsWith('.bin')) {
        contentType = 'application/octet-stream'
      }
      return callback(
        null,
        new Twilio.Response({
          statusCode: 200,
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': contentType,
          },
          body: fileContent,
        }),
      )
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
      return callback(
        null,
        new Twilio.Response({
          statusCode: 500,
          body: err.message,
        }),
      )
    }
  } else {
    return callback(
      null,
      new Twilio.Response({
        statusCode: 400,
        body: 'File not found',
      }),
    )
  }
}


I hope that it can help you! :D

tested, don't work; i have always the 403 error, do You have a simple code so i can test the load of the files?

Hello Alan, I tested your code and the error is in the "assetsPath" variable, instead use "assets['/abc.private.json'].path" you should use "assets['/abc.json'].path", without the ".private", I update my response to add an example

tested also with the different name, but nothing changed; the problem, I think is here:
const abcURL = "my twilio function url ?fileName=abc.private.json";
where I get the 403 error, where if i reach the link, it correct say "Unauthorized - you are not authenticated to perform this request", but either the html file get the file, this is why with the function we need to bypass this problem, but at the moment don't work

It's strange Alan, I deploy the function of example and I can retrieve the private file test.json that I've created, here https://playground-twilio-serverless-9451-dev.twil.io/getPrivateFile?fileName=test.json
Confirm that your function is public, not .protected and not .private.

Testing with a protected function it's return a 403 error Alan, confirm that your function is public.

Yes the function is public, the abc.private.json and def.private.json, are private, here is a screen: https://uploadpie.com/faWIit

Can you share the index.html or a similar file to test locally the importation?!

no, they are confidential files; in more, the link you send it, i can see what inside the json file, and i don't want that everyone can watch inside it, only the html code, need to read/load/access to it and use it; that's why the asset are private; and if on private don't work, can be done if the asset are protected? If yes do you have some sample of the code?

Alan, I deploy an example project in my github, I build a .html file that consumes the function to retrieve the private file content and show it on page, follow the link https://github.com/csevero/request-private-files-from-twilio, this link shows my .html retrieving data from private file, https://playground-twilio-serverless-9451-dev.twil.io/index.html

Ok, i copied all the file and code as on your github, and when load the page i get this errors:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
getPrivateFile?fileName=test.json:1     Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
index.html:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'N', "Not Found" is not valid JSON
The test.private.json, the visibility is set as private (icon with padlock), because as I say i need the json file private, and accessible only with a function
https://testfileprivati-1565.twil.io/index.html

Alan, I cannot get the file by this url, https://testfileprivati-1565.twil.io/getPrivateFile?fileName=test.json, if the file is in the project, the function should return the content to browser, confirm if the file is deployed on the assets folder correctly, can you get this file locally by function?

here is my configuration on twilio with the file: https://uploadpie.com/uXs8OV
and when i run locally there is this error: https://uploadpie.com/Dg6tMF

I cannot see the files, the links are expired, do you want to talk by discord?!

sure, drop the link
